# How do I find the location of a shortcut's icon in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a shortcut on my desktop who's icon I want to use on another shortcut.  I see how to set the icon (from properties).  However, I don't know the location of the icon.  How can I figure out where the icon is located that I want to use?

Here is a screenshot of the properties for the shortcut (Web URL).  You can see that if I click the "change icon" button it lists all of the standard available icons but does not point to the icon in the properties windows (Red "A" with black background.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The information is stored in .url file, which is just a simple text file, in the line "IconFile".

I tried opening an .url file in notepad, but it downloaded the corresponding website instead. So I went via the command line:

1. Open a "Command Prompt" by typing "cmd" in the start search and selecting "Command Prompt"
2. Navigate to the location of your .lnk or .url file
3. Links that are visible on all users' desktops are stored in "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
4. Use "type example.url" to show the content of the file.

For example you would find the icon of this  .url file in:

```
C:\Nodejs\nodejs.ico
```

Sample .url content:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
IconIndex=0
URL=http://nodejs.org/
IconFile=C:\Nodejs\nodejs.ico
```

Comment: If you place a shortcut to **Notepad** in your **SendTo** folder. you can use that to quickly view the text of a `.url` file.

Comment: You can also simply open notepad first, and then drag-and-drop the .url shortcut file to the notepad window.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Change Icon...* Button and then the *Look for Icons in this File:* Edit Box. Using the *Browse...* Button, you can locate the File that contains the Icons that you want to set.

[image: Setting an Icon for a Short-Cut]

For Web-Sites, you can use the *Change Icon...* Button and the *Browse...* Button as well.

[image: Setting an Icon for a Web-Site]

Comment: There is no "Shortcut" tab.  Only "General", "Web Document", "Security", "Details", "Previous Versions".  This is basically a link to a open a browser and a web site.

Comment: It would really help us if you could insert a little Screen-Shot of your own Situation, @GregH, so that we reduce the number of imagined things. If it is possible, then at least the _General_ Tab and the _Web Document_ Tab would be interesting to be seen.

Comment: There is a Shortcut tab in my own description above and also in hte screen shot above.  So if that is not what you need then please edit your question to provide screen shot clarity of your own

Comment: OP **didn't know** the location of the file containing the icon; that's what he was (and I am) **trying to figure out**! Unless I've completely lost the ability to read plain, well-written English...